# Is it better to use if/then/else to flip a boolean, or negation?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, boolean

Can I switch a boolean with one statement as effectively as with an if/then/else ?

Found this in another piece of code that is going into my app...

```
    private void whatever()
    {
        ////
        //// a bunch of stuff
        ////

        if (SomeBooleanValue)
        {
            SomeBooleanValue= false;
        }
        else
        {
            SomeBooleanValue = true;
        }
    }
```

Out of curiosity, I tried this...

```
    private void whatever_whatever()
    {
        //// 
        //// the same stuff
        //// 

        SomeBooleanValue = !SomeBooleanValue;
    }
```

...and walked through it in debug, and it *appears* that I get the same result.

Is there a good reason to use the if/then/else instead of the single line way ?

Comment: There is no good reason. The second way is just as correct as the first. (I hate to use the word _better_... but it's better)

Comment: You should do a simple example and check the generated object code. Any optimizing compiler should be able to do a branch reduction on this code and simply make the first equivalent to the second so pick whichever you prefer or is easier to read. If you literally compile this the 2nd is faster since you avoid the possible branch miss on the if statement (unless nothing relies on SomeBooleanValue) in which case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Use the first if you really don't like exclamation marks.

Comment: Honestly, I prefer the second method solely for readability.

Comment: When reading the !SomeBooleanValue, I get a little worried it might fail when it's null.

Comment: The value, as I understand the code (dangerous enough, etc.) will flip each time; i.e., do one thing one time, then the other way, then the first, and back and forth and so on.

Comment: @flup, interesting thought. Will the if/the/else survive a null value in SomeBooleanValue ?

Comment: If it's really a `bool` it cannot be null.  If it's a `bool?` (`Nullable<bool>`) your code would not compile.

Comment: Thank you to one and all. Comfort level has just increased. Off we go. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1-line way is perfectly fine, and the only reason why you'd use the `if/ else` structure is if you were doing other things aside from just toggling the boolean.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a good reason to use the if/then/else instead of the single line way

Not any that I can think of.  Using the `!` operator is cleaner and more intuitive for most programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the second one is better since it is more readable and compact (if/then/else IMO just adds unnecesary lines of code), that would be the only (but strong!) reason to prefer one from the other

Answer (score 2):

Due to compiler optimizations, it will be the same as using the ! operator, which is easier to read for other programmers.

However,

To improve performance, the CPU will try to predict the execution logic ahead of time.  For conditional (if/else) statements, it will try to predict the result of the condition and then load the rest of the logic.  If it chooses incorrectly, it must go back and re-calculate everything again, hence decreasing performance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

Answer (score 1):

Please, please, please write the code as a negation; it is the most succinct and concise expression of intent. If you write the code the first way, every reader of your code is going to waste time wondering why you did NOT write the simple negation.

Most code will be read, by you and others, many more times than it is written. Writing code that eases the reading process is, almost by definition, good code.